# When to call BillingClient.endConnection()?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, billingclient

From [Google doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient), it mentions

*When you are done with this object, don't forget to call endConnection() to ensure proper cleanup. This object holds a binding to the in-app billing service and the manager to handle broadcast events, which will leak unless you dispose it correctly. If you created the object inside the onCreate(Bundle) method, then the recommended place to dispose is the onDestroy() method.*

In my App, it will check purchase state from Google in loading page(LoadingActivity), then if user wants to purchase more products, he has to go to shopping page(ShoppingActivity).

As above, I should add **BillingClient.endConnection()** in LoadingActivity and ShoppingActivity.
Every time go to shopping page, it is necessary to recall **BillingClient.startConnection(this);** call **BillingClient.endConnection()** when leaving the shopping page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be called before applications's scope is destroyed. This is the Google's sample [project](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples). To be more specific this is the [BillingLifeCycleClass](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/blob/main/ClassyTaxiJava/app/src/main/java/com/sample/android/classytaxijava/billing/BillingClientLifecycle.java). This is the recommended way of using billing client, by attaching a LifeCylceObserver to it.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be strictly correct. In Google's ClassyTaxiJava (and/or Kotlin) Sample project, the `BillingClientLifecycle` class is a `LifecycleObserver` which is bound to the lifecycle of the `MainActivity`, not the `Application` scope. So `endConnection()` is called on `MainActivity#onDestroy()`.

Comment: Agree that the connection does not have to be application level scoped but rather having it on the activity also works fine, just make sure that the disconnection and retry logic is in place.

Comment: Hanging on to the client in an application seems to defeat the purpose of `endConnection()`: when an application ends, isn't the client is always destroyed since the process is killed?